# What are a few examples of mathematical objects which have the word "pseudo" used in the definition?

Tags: set-theory, definition

As motivation for this question, I wanted to create a short slide-show presentation for students on how mathematicians use the word ***pseudo***.

Wherever we see the word ***pseudo***, two different definitions are presented.

| Number | General | Specific Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a definition for a small set of mathematical objects | a definition of what a *desk* is |
| 2 | a definition for a broader larger set of mathematical objects | a definition of what a ***pseudo*** *desk* is, including dining tables and other furniture items with a flat surface on the top. |

That is not a *mathematical* definition.

My question is, what is an example of a definition published in a real book or real research paper which used the word "***pseudo***"?

I have seen such things, but I have forgotten most of the details.

---

Comment: This is very vague.  What instances are you thinking of?  People refer to "pseudo-code" for instance which is an informal term which generally means something like "an outline of the program which describes each step in ordinary language and not in any actual programming language."  But, as you can see from that example, it's not intended to have a precise meaning.

Comment: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14684/almost-but-not-quite-a-homomorphism) is an example, but I wouldn't exactly call these universally accepted usages.  I have never seen any examples that resemble what you describe.

Comment: @lulu: I don't think the question is vague at all, it's just not a purely mathematical question. The question is "how do mathematicians use the word 'pseudo'?" You answer that question by giving examples of such usages.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  But I've never seen any usage that resembles the description the OP provides.   If the OP is aware of such a usage, I think examples would be helpful.

Comment: There is the idea of a [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) of a matrix in linear algebra, which I recall being mentioned (but not discussed) in at least some introductory linear algebra books.

Comment: [Pseudosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere#:~:text=The%20name%20%22pseudosphere%22%20comes%20about,with%20constant%20positive%20Gaussian%20curvature.) is a standard usage, though the parallel with standard spheres isn't  immediately obvious.

Comment: @lulu. You defined ***pseudo***-code as an outline of a computer program, or algorithm, which describes each step in ordinary language (English, Spanish, etc...). However, the pseudo code is not written in any actual programming language, such as python. Outlines do not usually include many details. Most pseudo-code I have read is highly detailed, but not syntactically correct for most compilers or interpreters. For example, pseudo-code might look like [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) except that all of the curly-braces, semi-colons, and data-type declarations have been omitted.

Comment: Again, people use the term differently.  Personally, I would never assume that it required "highly detailed" writing, but perhaps others do.  And that's my point...the term is used loosely.  There's nothing at all wrong with that!  But terms that are used loosely don't lend themselves to formal definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is not how the word "pseudo" gets used. Typically a pseudo-X refers to something that is like an X but not actually an X, and such that Xes are not pseudo-Xes. So it is not (usually?) a generalization of X. For example:

- a [pseudovector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector) is like a vector, but vectors are not pseudovectors. Similarly a [pseudoscalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscalar) is like a scalar, but scalars are not pseudoscalars.
- a [pseudonatural transformation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pseudonatural+transformation) is like a natural transformation. I suppose in this case it does give natural transformations as a special case.
- a [pseudogroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudogroup) is like a group, but groups are not pseudogroups (actually it is a kind of [groupoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/groupoid)).

There are also a few other similar prefixes, such as ["quasi-"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry) (although this does sometimes refer to a generalization), ["pre-"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presheaf_(category_theory)) (also a generalization), or, more rarely, ["fake"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fake_projective_plane) (explicitly not a generalization).

Answer (score 4):

There's also [pseudoprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoprime), which are natural numbers that share some particular property with primes (typically one that is used in primality tests) but are not primes.
For example, Fermat pseudoprimes to base $b$ are composite numbers $x$ that divide $b^{x-1} - 1$.